# yii2 star widget does not appear

Tags: yii2, widget

I can not see `starwidget` in my yii2, I installed the widget, but it doesn't display stars.

See loading gif:
[image]

Following is my code:

```
echo '<label class="control-label">Rating</label>';
echo StarRating::widget([
    'name' => 'rating_2',
    'value' => 2.5,
    'disabled' => true
]);
```

Is there an explanation to this. Please help!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your js assets. Check if jQuery is not loading twice.